# Formatting date from datapicker

Tags: php, date, datepicker, strtotime

I am trying to output the date selected by a user in the format "Thu March 25th 2014" from a day that the user selects from a datepicker calendar.  The problem is that 1) datepicker sends me the date selected in the format 'mm-dd-yyyy' and I need to pass this string through strtotime in order to use as an input for the date() function, and strtotime considers a date using '-' as a separator to be in the international format 'dd-mm-yyyy'.  So the question is how can I switch a string 'mm-dd-yyyy' to 'dd-mm-yyyy' so that I can use that as input for strtotime?  Or am I doing this all wrong?

```
$schedule_pickup_date = $_POST['schedule_pickup_date'];   // this is the date from     datepicker
echo "Date: ".date('D F jS Y',strtotime($schedule_pickup_date));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` which allows you to tell PHP which format the original date is in. You can then format it from there.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $_POST['schedule_pickup_date']);
echo $date->format('D F jS Y');
```

Answer (score 2):

try using PHP DateTime class.
here is an example:

```
$time = $_POST['date']; 
$var = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i - d/m/Y', $time);
if ($var instanceof DateTime)
    $date = $var->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Thanks, similar to what @John Conde wrote, it works!